# SQL syntax error #1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run this sql statement but I got an error, What is the problem ? I have a table with name 'zips' to get all data which match the condition, what I'm trying to do is to casting `LAT`, `LONG` from `zips` table which are `varchar` type.

```
SELECT * FROM zips
         WHERE (
                CAST(LAT AS FLOAT) <= 41.009707145195 
                AND CAST(LAT AS FLOAT) >= 40.286092854805 
                AND CAST(LONG AS FLOAT) <= -73.307544588345 
                AND CAST(LONG AS FLOAT) >= -74.266455411655) 
                AND (
                    CAST(LAT AS FLOAT) != 40.6479 
                    AND CAST(LONG AS FLOAT) != -73.787
                    )
                 )
```

and the ERROR is

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FLOAT) <= 41.009707145195 AND CAST(LAT AS FLOAT) >=
40.286092854805 AND CAST(LON' at line 1
```

Comment: You have at least one, maybe two, parenthesis issues

Comment: more explain please ! @JohnConde

Comment: LONG is also a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html. There are more than enough words in the english language that you NEVER need to use a resrved word for a database object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM zips 
WHERE (
       CAST(LAT AS DECIMAL(10,6)) <= 41.009707145195 
      AND CAST(LAT AS DECIMAL(10,6)) >= 40.286092854805 
      AND CAST(`LONG` AS DECIMAL(10,6)) <= -73.307544588345 
      AND CAST(`LONG` AS DECIMAL(10,6)) >= -74.266455411655
      ) 
      AND 
     (
      CAST(LAT AS DECIMAL(10,6)) != 40.6479 
      AND CAST(`LONG` AS DECIMAL(10,6)) != -73.787
     )
```

**[LONG](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)** is a reserved keyword so put that inside the `backquotes`.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FLOAT) <= 41.009707145195
    AND CAST(LAT AS FLOAT) >= 40.286092854805
    AND ' at line 3

Comment: @user3003810:- Updated my answer. Please check now!

Comment: Great ! works perfect, thank you, but could you explain why float not work !!

Comment: @user3003810:- You need to provided the precision when you are using the decimal or float!